# Line integral and Green's formula

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration

I am trying to calculate this integral in two ways - as a line integral and using Green's theorem.
$$\int(x+y)^2dx-(x^2+y^2)dy$$
Integration area: left half of a circle centered at $(0, 0)$ and radius $a$.

My results:

1. $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}(a\cos(t)+a\sin(t))^2(-a\sin(t))-a^2(a\cos(t))dt=\frac{10a^3}{3}$
2. $\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}d\phi\int_{0}^{a}(-4r\cos(\phi)-2r\sin(\phi))rdr=\frac{8a^3}{3}$

My answers are not equal. What's my mistake?

Comment: Your path is not closed riight?

Comment: @weymarandres closed contour. [pic](https://imgur.com/a/qGiPeA2)

Comment: Then i believe that you need to integrate the line from $(0,-a)$ to $(0,a)$ in your linea integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the line integral along $x = 0$ from $(0, -a)$ to $(0, a)$

$r(t) = (0, t), - a \leq t \leq a$

As $\vec F = ((x+y)^2,-(x^2+y^2)), \vec F(r(t)) = (t^2, - t^2)$

$r'(t) = (0, 1)$

The line integral over the straight line segment is

$ \displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot r'(t) ~ dt = 
 \int_{-a}^a - t^2 ~ dt = - \frac{2a^3}{3}$

Adding to the line integral over the semicircle, your answers from both methods match.